# HttpContext Session is null when using Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, autofac, httpcontext

Using OWIN and AutoFac as the IoC container, I am trying to use Dependency Injection to inject HttpContext into a session state storage mechanism, but HttpContext.Session is null.  Also, I am not sure if it matters but the class that I am trying to inject HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current) into is an external dll that I have built as a nuget package.

Autofac registration, registers my Autofac module

```
 public static void Register(IAppBuilder app)
    {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            builder.RegisterModelBinderProvider();
            builder.RegisterFilterProvider();

            builder.RegisterModule(new GatewayModule());

            var container = builder.Build();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
            app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
    }
```

And the code for the autofac module:

```
public class GatewayModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<SessionStateTokenStore>()
            .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(HttpContextBase), new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)))
            .As<ITokenStore>().InstancePerRequest();
    }
}
```

However, when I look into my SessionStateTokenStore, _httpContext.Session is null.  Here is an image of my watch window in my debugger.
[HttpContext.Session is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeFlj.png)

Why is HttpContext.Session null and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you let Autofac resolves HttpContextBase, and see it solves the problem?

```
// HttpContext
builder.Register(c => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current) as HttpContextBase)
   .As<HttpContextBase>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Request)
   .As<HttpRequestBase>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Response)
   .As<HttpResponseBase>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Server)
   .As<HttpServerUtilityBase>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Session)
   .As<HttpSessionStateBase>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<SessionStateTokenStore>()
   .As<ITokenStore>().InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: Thank you!  That does work and I had tried it before but was being stupid and still registering .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(HttpContextBase), new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current))) after letting Autofac resolve HttpContextBase.  Turns out you can also just register the AutofacWebTypesModule which does the same things as you suggested, plus a bit more.